# Error al serializar: ilegal start of type expected ';'

Tags: java, jframe

Buenas estoy creando un formulario en swich se me ha ocurrido serializzar y deserializar porque tengo que guardarlo en un archivo. el problema es que  cuado meto

```
if (!miFichero.exists ()){
       f = new Formulario();
    }else {
            f = deserializa();
    }
```

me da un error ilegal start of type   expected ';' expected package mi fichero do not exit tanto en el if como en el else os dejo el swich completo con el serializa y deserializa

```
  public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    File miFichero = new File("c:\\lista.dat");
    Formulario f = null;

    if (!miFichero.exists ()){
       f = new Formulario();
    }else {
            f = deserializa();
    }


public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        persona1 = new Clases.Persona();
        txtUsuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        txtEdad = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtTelefono = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnGuardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnSalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BtnLimpiar = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, persona1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${usuario}"), txtUsuario, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        txtUsuario.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtUsuarioActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Usuario");

        jLabel2.setText("Password");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, persona1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${password}"), txtPassword, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        txtPassword.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtPasswordKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        txtEdad.setText("");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, persona1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${edad}"), txtEdad, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        txtEdad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtEdadActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        txtEdad.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtEdadKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Edad");

        jLabel4.setText("Telefono");

        txtTelefono.setText("");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, persona1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${telefono}"), txtTelefono, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        txtTelefono.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtTelefonoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        txtTelefono.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtTelefonoKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        btnGuardar.setText("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGuardarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Formulario");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 318, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        btnSalir.setText("Salir");
        btnSalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSalirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        BtnLimpiar.setText("Limpiar");
        BtnLimpiar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BtnLimpiarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(BtnLimpiar)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnGuardar)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(btnSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtTelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtEdad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 179, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtUsuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(txtEdad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtTelefono, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnGuardar)
                    .addComponent(btnSalir)
                    .addComponent(BtnLimpiar))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtUsuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void txtEdadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void txtEdadKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if ((c < '0' || c > '9')) {
            evt.consume();

        }
    }                                

    private void txtTelefonoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void txtTelefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if ((c < '0' || c > '9')) {
            evt.consume();
        }
    }                                    

    private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        dispose();
    }                                        

    private void BtnLimpiarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        txtUsuario.setText("");
        txtPassword.setText("");
        txtEdad.setText("");
        txtTelefono.setText("");
    }                                          

    private void txtPasswordKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String usuario;
        String password;
        int edad, telefono;
        usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
        password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
        edad = Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText());
        telefono = Integer.parseInt(txtTelefono.getText());
        Persona p = new Persona(usuario, password, edad, telefono);
        p.setUsuario(usuario);
        p.setPassword(password);
        p.setEdad(edad);
        p.setTelefono(telefono);
        f.aniadirPersona(p);

    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;


}
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton BtnLimpiar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSalir;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private Clases.Persona persona1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtEdad;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtTelefono;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUsuario;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
   private static void serializa(Formulario f) {
        FileOutputStream miFos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream miOos = null;
        try {
            String miFichero = "c:\\lista.dat";

            miFos = new FileOutputStream(miFichero);
            miOos = new ObjectOutputStream(miFos);
            miOos.writeObject(f);
            miOos.close();
            miFos.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                miFos.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                miOos.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Formulario deserializa() {
        FileInputStream miFis = null;
        ObjectInputStream miOis = null;
        Formulario f = null;
        try {
            String miFichero = "PilaDePartes.dat";
            miFis = new FileInputStream(miFichero);
            miOis = new ObjectInputStream(miFis);
            boolean seguir = true;
            while (seguir) {
                try {
                    f = (Formulario) miOis.readObject();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {
                    seguir = false;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            miOis.close();
            miFis.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                miFis.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                miOis.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return f;
    }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, incluye el mensaje completo de error

Comment: ilegal start of type  <identifier> expected ';' expected package mi fichero do not exit

Comment: Prueba quitando el espacio entre exists y los paréntesis.

Comment: @Alfabravo no no es eso ni en el exist ni entre el else y el corchete

Comment: Pon el if dentro del constructor o algún otro método y solucionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he averiguado la respuesta gracias a todos. El problema es que no serializaba donde devia, metí el metodo y no me di cuneta de que no lo llamaba en ningún sitio entonces obviamete no podía serializar.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que tu `if` está fuera de algún método.

Ese tipo de instrucciones tienen que estar contenidas dentro de algún método y no al nivel de la clase, por ejemplo, lo puedes poner dentro de tu constructor:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

    if (!miFichero.exists()){
        f = new Formulario();
    } else {
        f = deserializa();
    }
}
```

Comment: en prinicpuo no estaba en ningun metodo porque asi lo tenia en el main, pero vamos luego lo meti en uno y uan asi tp va

Comment: Técnicamente, el `main` también es un método, aunque no sería el lugar correcto para poner tu `if`. A mi modo de ver, el constructor es el lugar ideal para lo que requieres.

Comment: A mi me enseñaron a si pero si no crrees que es el sito correcto tu sabras mas que yo :P

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises con tu profe para que te quede más claro, por que así como lo tenías el programa nunca iba a correr. Pon el `if` en el constructor y prueba.